# Query to Update a value with matching records

Tags: ms-access, vba

Table `MissingT`, columns to work with are `WebID`, `AuthManager`

[image: Prior to update]

In the above table `WebID` 123 has "xyz" as Authmanager. But at the same time, there are other webid with 123 doesn't have an authmanager. I would like the query to update unique webid with the same authorizing manager. Basically, the table should look like below after running the query.

[image: Updated Table]

Comment: Have you created a table with WebId as the unique ID and AuthManager as a field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query does what I think you're asking:

If `WebID` is numeric datatype ...

```sql
UPDATE MissingT
SET AuthManager = DMin("AuthManager","MissingT","WebID=" & [WebID]);
```

If `WebID` is text datatype ...

```sql
UPDATE MissingT
SET AuthManager = DMin("AuthManager","MissingT","WebID='" & [WebID] & "'");
```

However, I don't understand why you apparently want to store the same combinations of `AuthManager` and `WebID` in multiple rows.  You could store only `WebID` in the main table and use that field to join to a lookup table which contains the distinct combinations of `AuthManager` and `WebID`.

Comment: I am unable to store webid in the maintable, since this table will be constantly deleted/append/update with an excel sheet imported to this database. Now, when I run the above query, it is giving a Type conversion failure. It still has the option to run the query which then deletes all the information under authmanager field.

Comment: I presumed `WebID` is numeric datatype.  I updated the answer to deal with `WebID` as text datatype.

Comment: Awesome! works beautifully. Yes, it wasn't a numeric field. Thank you so much.